# How to solve sporadic error loading of css icons?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having problems loading icons, but it is rare and difficult to reproduce the problem, as it occurs from time to time when updating with F5. It only occurs in bootstrap or other css source icons like Ionicons.

Here are some examples of how you are displaying the icons when the problem occurs.

**This is the page with problem to load icons**

[image: This is the page with problem to load icons]

**That's when the icons load**

[image: That's when the icons load]

The css is loaded from a file and the code class refers to fonts.

**Exemples from css file "ionicons.css"**

```
.ion-edit:before { content: "\f2bf"; }
```

**Utilization of class css in HTML**

```
        <a class="button_table" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDiv" onclick="DoSomething()">
            <span class="ion-edit"></span>
        </a>
```

**Inspecting the screen here, the css loaded like this:**

```
.ion-edit:before {  content: "ïŠ¿";}
```

Comment: Are you using SCSS? Are you setting the correct charset?

Comment: No, I using css, the charset is configured to "UTF-8". In first line of file css has @charset "UTF-8";